# Gap between countertop and wall

Tags: cabinets, countertops

My contractor installed base cabinets and countertop and there is a gap between wall and countertop backsplash. See the picture.

How can I hide that gap, what are my options to blend in the uneven gap ?

[image]

Comment: Have the contractor come back to do it right or have the contractor pay someone who will.  That is something I might expect from a 14 year old doing it the first time.

Comment: actually the gap is even, but the whole cabinet needs to be pushed against the wall, or it is standing on uneven floor, check with  leveling gauge, and try to shim it

Comment: Even if the floor wasn't level, the alleged "contractor" should have caught that and shimmed the front of the cabinets and trimmed them out at the floor.  This is a really bad/unacceptable job.   Also check your range, it might be not level either which is a total PITA when your trying to cook something with a bit of oil or butter and always runs to one side of the fry pan.

Comment: I agree with @Ruskes, that looks like the front of the cabinet needs to be shimmed up.  OP, can you show us what the side of the cabinet looks like?

Comment: Base cabinets itself were flush against the wall, it is problem only with countertop.

Answer (score 3):

That is beyond a poor job. The vertical member "backsplash" is what should be used to close gaps from uneven walls.  Get the "contractor" back. He should be ashamed of that job.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question directly, there is no way to blend or hide a gap of that size. As the previous answers have stated in similar form the only way to fix that is to take it apart and do it correctly from the floor up. If you try to hide or otherwise mitigate that gap you'll find yourself spending far more time and getting a far poorer result than just having the job corrected

Answer (score 0):

Just try to shim the left side of the cabinet (lift up and to the back) to see if it gets better.

You can always take legal steps or force the contractor to fix it.

He will probably tell you that he does not fixes uneven floors of crooked walls